# What font is used here?

Tags: font-identification

What's that font below "jak ja widzę swoje pismo"?

Edit: as two people already got confused - I know the font of header, it's quite obvious it's Comic Sans to everyone who used computer for more than calc. I'm asking about font of the text below comic sans, the one signed with by "W. A. Peterson".

[image: Here is image.]

Comment: jak ja widzę swoje pismo = as I see your letter :P , my guess the next one says: s it actually is... probably some post from 9gag or smthing.. :)) comic sans should just do for this purpuse

Comment: @FlaviusFrantz, "below" is key word there. And, as this text is in Polish and I am Pole, I already know what it means.

Comment: ah, I just saw your edit.. sorry :) [i wrote the translation for people that are not polish, like me...i was curios what it means]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's lovely, whatever it is.

If you can't find it, [Florens](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/agfa/florens/) is reasonably close, although it doesn't have the distinctive capital A.

Comment: Hmm, this one is nice, too, I'll stick with it if no-one knows what is the original font.

Answer (score 4):

1.take a screen grab to get the font into a bitmap.
2.In `Photoshop` remove any extraneous artifacts
3. go to [what the font](http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/)
4. upload and follow the online steps to help the site recognize the letters
5. It will output the fonts the text you uploaded resembles.

Have fun designing with your newly found favorite font.

Comment: Haven't said "Welcome" yet, so consider that done as of now. Generally, we like to see an answer that's more definitive, to a question that's more constructive, but this is a nice synopsis, and helpful to the less experienced.

Comment: Understood, will try to be more specific to the questions posted. And thanks for having me aboard.

Answer (score -2):

The font you seek is Comic Sans Bold.

However, if you are designing something, I strongly advise against it's use. There are far better looking fonts out there. Try www.dafont.com for inspiration.

Comment: Read the question again: I'm asking about the font *below* text saying "jak ja widzę swoje pismo" - I know that that text is written using Comic Sans.

Answer (score -3):

Here's the result from myfonts.com:
https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/layarbahtera/layar-bahtera/

[image: W.A. Peterson]

Comment: Clearly not the same font - just look at the cap A.